# What does "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'" mean?

Tags: python

```
#Finding the volume of a box
print("Welcome to box volume calculation! Please answer the following questions.")
x = float(raw_input("How wide is the box? ")),
y = float(raw_input("How high is the box? ")),
z = float(raw_input("How long is the box? ")),

"The volume of the box is " + str(x*y*z) + " units cubed."
```

The error message I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python25\Scripts\Randomness.py", line 22, in <module>
"The volume of the box is " + str(x*y*z) + " units cubed."
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'
```

Comment: Why do you have trailing commas? What tutorial or other resource is suggesting this?

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of your commas in the lines where you are asking for input.  Those lines should read:

```
x = float(raw_input("How wide is the box? "))
y = float(raw_input("How high is the box? "))
z = float(raw_input("How long is the box? "))
```

Explanation ... a statement of the form:

```
x = a, b, c
```

creates a tuple of three elements, and equally:

```
x = a,
```

creates a tuple of **one** element.  So here, a statement like:

```
x = float(raw_input(...)),
```

creates a tuple of one element, that element being your input!

Answer (score 2):

Your *variables* are tuples not floats:

```
x = float(raw_input("How wide is the box? ")),
#                                            ^
```

The trailing comma makes your object a tuple containing one float:

```
>>> x = 2.2,
>>> type(x)
<class 'tuple'>
```

What to do? Remove all the trailing commas:

```
x = float(raw_input("How wide is the box? "))
```

**Extra**: The error was relating to something you didn't intend, for which the interpreter has rightly assumed you are trying to *expand* a tuple using another tuple. However, tuples can only be *expanded* using integers:

```
>>> x = 2.2,
>>> x * 5
(2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2)
```